# Trace impedance issue in via antipad

Tags: impedance, layout

We have simulated the S-parameter using the SIwave tool. In that, we have done the impedance scan for the traces and we have found some higher impedance >100E which is supposed to be 85E near the via. To get the proper reference for the traces which is routed on the bottom, we have provided dog bone anti pad in the underneath ground layer. Still, the impedance is not proper as expected. Please suggest how to reduce the impedance in the highlighted area as shown in the attached image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try widening the lines a little but my experience is that it doesn’t bear out any improvement in the measured results.

What frequency range are you working to? The line length is so short that you probably won’t even see the impedance bump in real data unless you have extremely high frequency equipment and capability. If frequencies were so high then I get killed by the via structures themselves more than the fan out.

Comment: The frequency range is 16GHz, I.e PCIe GEN4 signals

Comment: I apologize for the (very) tardy reply here. I'd probably call 85 ohms good enough. It's 20dB return loss so the reflection is quite minimal. The PCB house will guarantee around 10% impedance control as well..

That said. at 16Gbps you've got a 16.5ps UI. Assuming an effective Er of 3.5 for microstrip, that's 1.6e8 m/s or 0.16mm/ps. Your 16.5ps is 2.65mm trace length. You can calculate the voltage reflected as a percentage to get an idea of the size and timing of the reflection relative to your budget.